# Passing multi-line text parameter from VB.NET to npgsql

Tags: vb.net, npgsql

I have a working Postgres function that take a multi-line text parameter "_list" and uses `regexp_split_to_table(TRIM(_list), '\r\n')` to create a table with each line of text as a row.

I now want to call this from VB.NET reading the value from a textarea. I am using `pgCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_list", NpgsqlDbType.Text, my_list)`.

However VB is replacing the linebreaks with vbLF and my Postgres function is seeing it as a single line. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regex_split_to_table` looks to take a regex as its split matcher..

..so just make it `regexp_split_to_table(TRIM(_list), '\r?\n')` (added a question mark after `\r`) so that it matches 0 or 1 carriage returns followed by a line feed when splitting. This way it doesn't matter if your program, or any other program, supplies CRLF or LF..

Answer (score 0):

Using
`pgCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_list", NpgsqlDbType.Text, my_list.Replace(vbLf, vbCrLf))`
has solved the problem